# Eclipse terminating without message during assignment of 2D-Array element

Tags: c, arrays, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm experiencing odd behavior in Eclipse / C. I have the following type  declared in, lets say, a.h.

```
typedef double sig_type[3];
```

and the following in, lets say, b.c

```
typedef struct filter_kind {
. . . 
sig_type *     fil_buff;         //The buffer for all values
. . .
} filter_kind;


 int init_filter(filter_kind * filter, const sig_type init_data[],
            const int data_len) {

    if (filter->data_buff_len != data_len) {
        return -1
    }

    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < filter->data_buff_len; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < OUT_NUM; j++) {
            (filter->fil_buff)[i][j] = init_data[i][j];   //prog exits on this line.
        }
    }

    filt_coeffs(filter);

    return 0;
}
```

I have a specified function to return a pointer to a malloced filter_kind structure, which mallocs fil_buff. When I use this creation function, and pass the newly created filter_kind pointer to init_filter, the function unexpectedly exits when assigning to (filter->fil_buff)[][] -- with almost no note other than "gdb" in the Debug view.

I've dropped in some probe variables, and viewed them during debug, and nothing seems abnormal up until this point. I can read from the array fine, just cannot assign. Am I doing something wrong here?

And lastly, here is the constructor function with corresponding allocation functions.

```
filter_kind * create_filter(const double f_lo, const double f_hi,
        const double samp_r, win_type window_t, fil_type filter_t,
        const int buff_len) {

    filter_kind * filter;
    sig_type * fil_buff;
    int err = 0;

    /* allocate filter struct */
    filter = (filter_kind *) malloc(sizeof(filter_kind));

    err = (filter != NULL ) ? 0 : -1;
    if (err == -1) {
        return NULL ;
    }
    memset(filter, 0, sizeof(filter_kind));

    /* allocate filter data members */
    err = alloc_buffs(win_coeffs, fil_coeffs, fil_buff, buff_len);
    if (err == -1) {
        return NULL ;
    }

    //assign other structure values...
    filter->fil_buff = fil_buff;


    return filter;
}


static int alloc_buffs(double * win_coeffs, double * fil_coeffs,
        sig_type * fil_buff, const int buff_len) {
    int err = 0;

//allocate other buffers...
    err = alloc_st_buff(fil_buff, buff_len);
    if (err == -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

static int alloc_st_buff(sig_type * st_buff, const int buff_len) {
    const int num_bytes = sizeof(sig_type) * buff_len;

    st_buff = (sig_type *) malloc(num_bytes);
    const int err = (st_buff != NULL ) ? 0 : -1;

    if (err == -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    memset(st_buff, 0, num_bytes);
    return 0;
}
```

and for what it's worth, designed to be used as follows

```
filter_kind * filter;
filter = create_filter(...);

/* Load data into array of sig_type, i.e. sig_type arr[40] */

init_filter(filter, arr, 40);

/* more code... */
```

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong just by looking at this code. If you have problem with dynamic allocation of the memory, then you should provide also code with how you allocate the memory. I think, that something with allocation is wrong or you exceed table fil_buff or init_data. Also you are not using data_len, which is rather amusing. Is data_buff_len is set properly?

Comment: @DawidPi Hi -- I do use data_len, and have a few other very small lines of code that I'm certain aren't affecting anything. Removed in order to lean out the code. Was fearing it might be issue with allocation, I'll make an edit to with my constructor. Thanks!

Comment: @DawidPi The post has been updated. Relevant code appears at bottom of post -- also edited to omit what I believe to be irrelevant details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok problem is with allocating buffers (calling allocating function):

```
sig_type * fil_buff;
err = alloc_buffs(win_coeffs, fil_coeffs, fil_buff, buff_len);
filter->fil_buff = fil_buff;
```

So what is happening here:

- Create pointer to a table called `fil_buff`,
- call function alloc_buffs with **copies** of pointers to `fil_buff` etc.,
- assign **not changed** `fil_buff` to a structure.

Every time function takes argument it makes a *copy* of it. So when you passed a pointer, then function made a copy of this pointer (and it was operating on a copy of the pointer), thus original pointer (before function call) is not changed. You should pass pointer to the pointer you want to operate on. The way it could be done is:

```
err = alloc_buffs(win_coeffs, fil_coeffs, &fil_buff, buff_len);
                                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

then your `fil_buff` can really be changed, but you have to adjust your function to take proper arguments and to properly operate on them. I guess the same mistake has been made with other buffers.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the issue. Obviously arrays are automatically pass by reference, and I have been operating on the assumption pointers behave in the same way. Even if they are technically a value, you're ostensibly still operating on the same piece of data.

Just ran a small test that appears to back this up. I could still be wrong-- but here it is (painfully unformatted)
void addme(int * one) {
 (*one) = (*one) + 1;
}

int main() {

 int one = 1;
 int * first = &one;

 addme(first);
printf("%i, %i", one, *first);
}. 

prints "2, 2"

Comment: above is correct, but you passed pointer to the value you wanted to change. malloc is returning pointer to the allocated space in memory and you want to use this to assign this to fil_buff. You want to change fil_buff so you should pass a pointer to it. See this:#include <stdlib.h>


void allocatePtr(int* ptr){
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
}

int main(void)
{
    int* pointerToInt;
    printf("%p\n", pointerToInt);

    allocatePtr(pointerToInt);
    printf("%p\n", pointerToInt);

    return 0;
}
this is what is happening in your code. Pointer did not change.